# jQuery EasyUI tabs load by href, the tab content can not loaded in IE/Chrome browser etc. but can be loaded well in Firefox

Tags: javascript, tabs, load, jquery-easyui

I created some tabs using jQuery EasyUI tabs. The content of the tab1 loaded by href method(I do not want apply 'iframe' method), it is can be loaded in Firefox well,but can not be loaded in other browsers for example IE or Chrome etc. always in loading... status. the code as follows：

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery EasyUI Tabs Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="tabsDemo" style="margin-left:20px;width:1100px;height:400px">
    <div title="default" class="easyui-layout" style="padding:10px">
      <h2>Default tab</h2>
      <table id="safett1" class="easyui-datagrid">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-options="field:'id'">id</th>
              <th data-options="field:'task'">task</th>
              <th data-options="field:'status'">status</th>
              <th data-options="field:'question'">question</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div title="tab1" class="easyui-layout" style="padding:10px">
    hello world
    </div>
    <div title="tab2" class="easyui-layout" style="padding:10px">
    I have 9 golden fish
    </div>
  </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#tabsDemo').tabs({
      onSelect: function(title, index) {
        var tab = $('#tabsDemo').tabs('getSelected');
        if(index == '1') {
          $('#tabsDemo').tabs('update', {
            tab: tab,
            type:'all',
            options: {
              href: './tab1.html', //the new content URL
            }
          });
        } else if(index == '2') {
          $('#tabsDemo').tabs('update', {
            tab: tab,
            options: {
              title:'newTab',
              href: 'http://www.apple.com/', //the new content URL
            }
          });
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  })
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```html
<!-- tab1.html -->
<h2>Good students</h2>
<table id="safett2" class="easyui-datagrid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-options="field:'id'">id</th>
          <th data-options="field:'name'">name</th>
          <th data-options="field:'description'">description</th>
          <th data-options="field:'score'">score</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```